# Where will Git Desktop push when on a local branch

Tags: git, github

I am new to Github Desktop, when I switched to a branch, it has the following [image], now from what I understand nd what my fear is if I do  push on it, it will push to origin/master. is it so? because I do not want to push to origin/master but rather pull/merge from master.

Why is Github desktop so confusing.

Comment: If you are on branch `mybranch`, push by default means push thru `origin/mybranch` up to remote `mybranch`.

Comment: If you are in doubt, use the command line. A GUI you don’t understand or trust is much worse than the command line. I recommend SourceTree but even then I often switch to the Terminal (which is easy to do). Knowing “real” git (meaning the command line) is crucial always.

Comment: @matt I know git command line, my frustration is that I downloaded it using Github desktop, so `.git` don't exist in the project folder

Comment: @matt also the confusing part is `origin` it should say `origin/mybranch`

Comment: It doesn't say `origin/master` or `origin/mybranch`. `origin` is the name of a _remote_, as I said before.

Comment: "so .git don't exist in the project folder" Oh, I find that hard to believe. That's how git _works_; the repository is _always_ in the project folder.

Comment: Yeah, you're just wrong about that. In GitHub Desktop choose Repository > Open In Terminal. In Terminal, say `ls -al` and you will see that this is just an ordinary working tree with a `.git` repo inside it. So you can just start giving command-line commands right there.

Comment: ok thanks, now my github says that 'I merged master in mybranch', whereas it should say 'I merged mybranch in master' isn't that wrong?

Comment: You have not revealed what you _did_. I recommended that you operate at the command line, and you said you know how to do that. Did you? What did you do there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209930/discussion-between-nofel-and-matt).